# QRegExp does not operate as expected

Tags: c++, qt, split, qregexp

I have a QString "mystring" which is captured from the return value from this shell command:

```
    df /storage/sdcard0/
```

The string captured is:

```
   Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
   /storage/sdcard0/        5.5G     3.9G     1.6G   4096
```

I convert the QString to a QStringList with:

```
   QStringList list=mystring.split(QRegExp("\\s"));
   int i = list.count();
```

However, when I examine the list:

```
  for( int a = 0; a < i; a = a + 1 )
             qDebug() << list[a];

"Filesystem"
""
"Size"
""
"Used"
""
"Free"
""
"Blksize"
""
"/sdcard/"
""
"5.5G"
""
"3.9G"
""
"1.6G"
""
"4096"
""
""
```

I've omitted a bunch of the "" for brevity.   If I use the same split with a
typed-in string it works perfectly.

```
       QString mystring = "This is a sentence with words"
```

qDebug shows:

```
"This"
"is"
"a"
"sentence"
"with"
"words"
```

How can I stop these "" from being added to the QStringList? Can this be corrected with a different QRegExp?

Comment: Sorry: QStringList list=mystring.split(QRegExp("\\s"),QString::SkipEmptyParts);

Comment: Works, thanks!  If you add as a answer, I'll accept it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `QString::split(const QRegExp &rx, SplitBehavior behavior = KeepEmptyParts) const` there is an optional parameter `SplitBehavior` that allows you to specify how to process the empty parts. If you leave the default QString::split() will keep the empty parts. To skip you need to set this to `QString::SkipEmptyParts`.

So change your split to the following:

```
QStringList list=mystring.split(QRegExp("\\s"),QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```